# wrong error message

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, python, gnome-terminal

i have ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, along with python 2.7. at some point i have modified my `PYTHONPATH` so that it can work with `tensorflow`. however, if i type `ls-` into the terminal, then the error i'm receiving is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 23, in <module>
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, io, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 335, in <module>
    import copyreg
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/copyreg/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
    if not enabled():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 335, in <module>
    import copyreg
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/copyreg/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 23, in <module>
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, io, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 335, in <module>
    import copyreg
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/copyreg/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```

and it should just be

```
bash: ls-: command not found
```

i'm kinda a picky person, so it somewhat bothers me. thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42214414/4464570 How exactly did you modify the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: by editing `~/.bashrc` and `export $PYTHONPATH:` etc.?

Comment: Actually I meant what value you set it to...

Comment: `export PYTHONPATH=/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. there was a bug that i couldn't get around in `tensorflow` so directly distilling the path into `PYTHONPATH` solves my problem, hence the patch.

Comment: i  think i figure out the problem. `sudo apt remove python3` solves  the problem and creates another because my `software-center` and `firefox` are gone... thanks a lot Byte Commander!

Comment: These locations should be configured by default without manually adding them. Please try to `unset PYTHONPATH` and check the output of `python -c 'import sys;print("\n".join(sys.path))'`

Comment: Hey, nobody ever told you to uninstall `python3`. Try if you can reinstall it easily with `sudo apt install python3` as well as all the other packages depending on it that got removed too.

Comment: it's OK :) i get used to `python2.7` anyway. `python3.5` is purely a pain... lol. thanks a lot though!

Comment: No no no. Python 3 is an important part of many system components. You NEED it!

Comment: so are you saying the system wouldn't actually function properly without `python3`?

Comment: Yes. Many programs are actually written in Python 3 and can not work without it. Go get it back.

Comment: done. yes i did get it back, and my problem seems to go away. not sure if there is anymore after rebooting, but so far i'm quite happy with it. waiting for backup before rebooting.